# Area select event for R leaflet in shiny

Tags: r, mouseevent, shiny, leaflet

I've played with the mouse click event in leaflet using the following code:

```
mymap=leaflet()
selected_site=eventReactive(input$mymap_marker_click,{
      event <- input$mymap_map_marker_click
      return(mydt[Long==event$lng & Lat==event$lat,get("sites")])
    })
```

to display a plot from a `data.table`  after a click on a point of the map. 
Now, I'd like to select an entire area then display data binding to it.

In other terms, I'd like to select not a couple of (Lat,Long) but a series of (Lat1, Long1)....(Latn,Longn)

Is there a mean to do it in leaflet ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score -1):

You just have to instantiate a `L.Polygon` per area, and attach an event handler to it: http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/zab/edit?html,console,output

Keep in mind that you can make areas transparent (zero opacity but `fill` option still set to `true`) and still get mouse events from them.

Comment: yes, but this is a static polygon. What if the polygon is generated on mouse selection?

Comment: As long as you have instances of `L.Polygon`, you can attach event handlers to them.You have a few alternatives: do that for every polygon that is added to the map (and that you want to keep track of), or use a `L.FeatureGroup`, attach a event handler to the feature group (not to every polygon), then add the polygons inside the `L.FeatureGroup`. As explained in the Leaflet docs, events fired in features inside feature groups bubble up to the group.

Comment: The link in this answer is broken.